# communication between 7 bluetooth modules

Tags: bluetooth

I’m working on a project where a 7 bluetooth modules need to communicate with each other simultaneously. But i am unable to pair two bluetooth modules. Please guide me on how to make simultaneously communication between 7 bluetooth modules.

P.S. I am using hc 05 bluetooth modules.

Comment: I'd work on getting 2 of them talking before starting on PAN...

Comment: Did you had successful communication between two boards? I tried using Arduino boards too. Each time it is giving garbage values(which I checked through Serial Monitor).

Comment: "Please guide me" is not a question. Note that "how do I pair two BT modules" is not exactly on topic here either.

Answer (score 4):

The HC 05 modules will only pair with one device at a time.  You might be able to come up with a scheme where a module configured as a master acts as a hub communicating with 6 modules configured as slaves.  The master would pair with each one in turn, transfer data, and pair with the next.

It seems like a lot of effort though, are you sure you can't use Zigbee, ANT or another wireless method that already includes mesh networking features?

Comment: I haven't consider  yet to use zidbee. Does zigbee can be supported by 89c51 processors?

Answer (score 2):

As Adam davis has said, a 'time share' sort of thing can be done for a master HC-05 device where it cycles through the list of detectable bluetooth devices and services them. Make sure you think about your network setup first, and make some logical choices about how you are going to prepare data to send, and how often this needs to occur. 
If your system needs fast response times over wireless, perhaps this method will not be fast enough to deal with changes. If it was merely logging 7 different zone temperatures, which is a slow 'system', then it will be fine. Perhaps you could elaborate what your application/final goal is for this network of 7 bluetooth devices?

Did you know that bluetooth is "high power" and "short range", unless you use the top of the range new bluetooth devices? HC-05 is kind of low end/old technology, it will not be efficient or long range in comparison to newer modules.

You should check out the Synapse RF266 and other RF-Engine devices. They are super easy to use, and allow very fast, mesh-style network/communications between nodes including broadcasting (to all addresses). A Synapse node connected to a computer can act as a data logger very easily through serial->USB, and a quick C# or Python program to log the incoming serial.